# How to use TextEdit of Android instead of Flutter Textfield

Tags: flutter

the textfield of Flutter is not very easy to use，Please tell me how to use Android native textedit instead of textfield in Flutter

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not easy to use?

Comment: If you use native Edittext that won't work on IOS, also please read [Build a form with validation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) it is really simple to use.

Comment: Android keyboard function keys are not available：https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27880，The Chinese mobile phone also has the function of automatically selecting and segmenting words, and the Flutter cannot be used.Officially, it's the problem, but even if it's solved, I think automatic word segmentation can't be used:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13015

Comment: Here is the documentation to TextEdit: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText, but I don't understand how you plan to use it. I'd be happy to try and explain Flutter's Text Field if you show me your issue(s). Thanks.